# Why isn't my war file containing all of the contents?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, war

I have a web application. I have created a war file out of the "export" option from Eclipse. However, the war file only contains the META-INF and the WEB-INF folders. There are no .java or .class files at all.

I also tried another method using the Maven "clean install" goals. This one also gives me the exact problem as above. Where am I going wrong? Can someone help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: without the description of your project layout or the pom.xml? No we can't help. Please add these information. Are your sources in src/main/java and the web resources in src/main/webapp?

Comment: Actually "mvn package" should already put The ready-assambled war file into the target directory. No need to install.

Answer (score 0):

Please chcek if you have your code in default src path for maven (src\main\java)

Answer (score 0):

If your project is an Eclipse project you need to make sure you created it as a 'Dynamic Web Project' so Eclipse attaches the right Facets so it knows how to build the .war.

If it's a maven project, you at least include

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

so Maven knows how to package your app.

If you run 'mvn package', assuming your pom.xml is configured correctly, you should get a .war file created in the target dir.

Sounds like something is not configured right - can you share more info about your source project structure and how it is configured?